# Removing nsdata stored in nsuserdefault

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, nsdata

I am saving image data (`NSData`) as an Array in `NSUserDefault`,while relaunching the app and try to remove the imagedata from the array stored in `NSUserDefault`,the data is not removing ..

Comment: So, you want to clear NSUserDefault when you launch app. Am I right?

Comment: no,I want to remove single object from the array stored in NSUserdefault

Comment: post your code ...

Comment: Don't store `NSData` in user defaults.

Comment: Can u show something that u have tried? Adding code how you save the data and how u remove it will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have store image data with key 'imagedata' something like below line of code

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imageData forKey :@"imageData"];
```

How to remove data stored for key imageData is as below line of code:

```
 NSMutableArray *arr= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"imageData"]]mutableCopy];// If array is not mutable then make it mutable then remove
[arr removeObjectAtIndex:index];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:arr forKey :@"imageData"];
```

After checking your code  updating my answer 
**UPDATE**

Try  method `removeObjectIdenticalTo` of array.

Comment: I am stored an array of imagedata

Comment: NSData *tempData=UIImagePNGRepresentation([randomArray objectAtIndex:i]);
                                   [randomArrayData removeObject:tempData];
 NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [defaults setObject:randomArrayData forKey:@"FbPhoto"];
            [defaults synchronize];

Comment: [randomArray objectAtIndex:i] is an uiimage

Answer (score 0):

```
//sample data
NSArray *photos = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"photo1.png",@"photo2.png",@"photo2.png", nil];

//To save the array of data
NSUserDefaults *userPreferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userPreferences setObject:photos forKey:@"FbPhoto"];
[userPreferences synchronize];

//To remove
[userPreferences removeObjectForKey:@"FbPhoto"];
[userPreferences synchronize];
```

Comment: post your code..and also check the key used for saving and removing is same.

Comment: Retrieving imagedata array NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     randomArrayData=[[defaults objectForKey:@"FbPhoto"] mutableCopy] ;

Comment: this code is for retrieving data from user defaults but the question is about removing from user defaults.so post the code for the removing

Comment: NSData *tempData=UIImagePNGRepresentation([randomArray objectAtIndex:i]); [randomArrayData removeObject:tempData]; NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; [defaults setObject:randomArrayData forKey:@"FbPhoto"]; [defaults synchronize];

Comment: [randomArray objectAtIndex:i] is an uiimage

Comment: your trying to remove the image data from array(randomArrayData) only not from the user preference.that's why the array of data is still in the user defaults. follow the above code snippet mentioned in the answer.